# If $A\subseteq B$, then $A'\subseteq B'$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Proof or counterexample: If $A\subseteq B$, then $A'\subseteq B'$. 
I have no idea where to start. Only thing I know is the definition of limit points.

$A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $A'$?

Comment: $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$.

Comment: Have you tried the standard pattern of showing inclusions? By that I mean: Start with „Let $x$ be in $A^\prime$. This means X. We want to show that $x$ is in $B^\prime$. We know that Y holds.“ and see how you can connect the argument by using the definitions.

Comment: The thing is I have a feeling that this is a false statement, but I cannot find counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in A'$, then for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists point $y_U \in U$ such that $y_U\in A\setminus\{x\}$.  As $A\subseteq B$, $y_U\in B$.  What conclusion can you make?

> Therefore, for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, the point $y_U\in U$ is a point distinct from $x$ that is also in $B$.  By the definition of limit points, $x$ must be a limit point of $B$, whence $A'\subseteq B'$.

Comment: I understand what you write here, but I do not see any good for this.

Comment: Can you guess at least whether I'm proving the positive, or providing a counterexample?

Comment: a counterexample?

Comment: This indicates that you don't really understand the concept of limit points (and probably methods of proof as well).  I am proving the positive.  That is, I want to show $A'\subseteq B'$.  If I am to prove this, what must I do?

Comment: you need to show a arbitrary point that in $A'$ is also in $B'$

Comment: Precisely!  So, how does my argument above show that $x$ is also in $B'$?

Comment: you showed a point that is different from $x$ is in $B$, but how does it connect with $B'$?

Comment: That is precisely why I think you still haven't grasped this concept.  There is an open neighborhood $U$ for a reason.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it, can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: See the hidden box in my edited answer.

Comment: oh thanks, I think I know where I struggle at. If $y_u$ is different from $x$ and it is in $B$, then it is automatically satisfy the definition of limit point. Am I right?

Comment: Yes.  That is what eluded you for a while I guess.

Comment: another quick question, I see you saying "open neighborhood" but my book uses "open set", can I consider these two are the same thing?

Comment: An open neighborhood of $x$ is just an open set that contains $x$.

Comment: thanks a lot. for the situations like this, where I fail to remember the definition, how can I avoid this?

Comment: I don't know how to help you, not knowing you personally.   It would be lame to simply suggest that you should practice more, even more so with concepts you struggle with.  However, I think this lame advice is virtually what most mathematicians are doing.

Comment: @Batominovski I've undeleted my answer accordingly. I just felt that yours had  already covered what was being asked, and the question was rather 'classic' to need an alternative approach. I appreciate the comment, though :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** argue by the contrapositive: that is, show that if $x \not \in B'$, then $x \not \in A'$.

> Take $x \not \in B'$. Therefore, there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ with $U \setminus \{x\} \cap B = \emptyset$. Hence $U \setminus \{x\} \cap A \subset U \setminus \{x\} \cap B = \emptyset$, and so $U \setminus \{x\} \cap A = \emptyset$, or equivalently $x \not \in A'$.

Comment: thank you, I have already understand this concept.